# Place a button outside my layout on DialogFragment

Tags: android, layout, modal-dialog

First of all, take a look at this screeshot:

[image: Screenshot]

I want to place a close button in this modal like this:
[image]

**But I can't figure out how to do that, here is going my layout file:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="br.com.makadu.makaduevento.ui.fragments.wizardInteligenceArtificial.WizardAIFifthStep">


<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title_subjects_schedule_suggestion"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/screen_title_top_bot_padding"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/screen_title_top_bot_padding"
        android:background="@color/Verde2"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/txt_medium"
        android:text="@string/str_screen_title_subjects"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/str_according_to_your_interests_title"
        style="@style/Theme.DefaultTextView.PrimaryDark.Bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/tv_according_interests"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_title_subjects_schedule_suggestion" />


    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/elv_suggested_schedule"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_according_interests"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/b_confirm_schedule">


    </ExpandableListView>



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b_confirm_schedule"
        style="@style/Theme.DefaultButton.Purple.Radius"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/str_confirm_schedule_button"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.
Well stackoverflow is asking me to explain better my problem, but i guess the pictures explain it selfs, so I'm now just writing any no sense text.

Answer (score 1):

**The first solution**, it will work 100% but I think not beautiful:
You can make root layout transparent and put in it needed visible views. U can set `OnClickListener` for root view to hide dialog on tap out visible views.
**The second solution**, maybe it will work I can't check now:
You can turn off `clipPadding` for root view and move yo close button out of visible.
P.S. I wrote from phone so it has not good view format and without samples.

Answer (score 0):

I runed on similar issue, u should Create a LinearLayout With a gravity center and margin with background transparent, the add a RelativeLayout with the content of your dialog.

In the RelativeLayout u can use the **android:layout_alignParentRight="true" & android:layout_alignParentTop="true"** for the ImageView containing the close button (probably u will need to use some margins too) so it will be displayed above the textview containing the title of your dialog.

I hope this helped you, tomorrow i will try to send u a code for this !